# When does instruction pointer get zero while debugging?

Tags: cpu-registers, cpu-architecture, processor, program-counter

What are the possible scenarios when a program counter or instruction pointer get zero ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might happen if you have a NULL function pointer since depending on the compiler and instruction set you might trigger a jump to 0. This might also happen with c++ if you're using a virtual function and the vtable has a NULL entry.

I haven't confirmed this though, just a guess

Comment: Buffer overflows (particularly those overwriting the return address) could result in a zero return address which becomes a zero instruction pointer/program counter. I **seem** to recall (vaguely) that some systems used a zero return address at the base of the stack to provide an implicit exit (trying to execute the instruction at address zero would generate an exception, invoking the OS).